# Merging multiple .html Extent Reports into one html in .NET

Tags: c#, html, extent

So if I have Test1.html and Test2.html and need to combine all tests result from the files into 1 html, is this possible? There are other packages that can combine html files, but they dont work very well with extent reports.

I have tried Extent Reports v2-v4 and cant seem to find anything simple that can do this for me.

More information on the test environment: We have 100+ machines running at the same time doing tests. Each machine uploads the html report to a central jenkins server. Once the reports are there, we need those combined into 1 html.
Ive looked at other packages that are designed to combine html and xml files into one, but those packages just mangle the data inside and the final report isnt very helpful. I was hoping that Extent had functionality inside that could do this for us.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than having Extent Reports create a HTML file for each test and then trying to merge them afterwards, have you tried telling Extent Reports to write the output from all tests to a single HTML file? I'm sure I've done this before, I just don't have the details to hand right now.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that we have many machines in a virtual environment, all of which upload the reports back to the central jenkins machine. So we basically end up with 100+ reports on the jenkins machine, and it would be great to have these combined into 1 html.

Comment: Thank you, the fact the tests are running on multiple machines and so you're going to get multiple HTML files is an important detail which I think you ought to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75415117/edit) into your question. So we really are looking at a question about how to merge multiple HTML files into one file, rather than how to avoid having to merge them. Good to get that clarified :-)